# Создание визуализации математических формул на сайте

Tags: javascript

Как можно реализовать визуализацию (замену символов) мат. формул на сайте, заключая их в какие-либо символы (например слэш и звёздочка), по типу:

```
/* f(x) = x^2+4x-5 */
```

И данный кусочек на сайте выглядел как нормальная формула

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно с помощью [katex](https://katex.org/).

```js
katex.render(" f(x) = x^2 + 4x - 5", document.querySelector('#formula'));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.5.1/katex.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.5.1/katex.min.js"></script>
<div id='formula'></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за библиотеку, очень выручили :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/#gettingstarted)

```html
   

  <title>MathJax example</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
  <script id="MathJax-script" async
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3.0.1/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js">
  </script>

<p>
  When \(a \ne 0\), there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
  \[x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.\]
</p>
```